# Mercurial: finding the latest commit on branch foo that was merged into branch bar

Tags: mercurial

I'm using Mercurial with two named branches, `foo` and `bar`. Periodically, `foo` is merged into `bar`. How do I find the latest `foo` commit that was thus merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this would do it:

```
hg log -r `last(branch("foo") and ancestors("bar"))`
```

That finds the last commit that is on branch foo and and ancestor of the any commit on branch bar.

If that's not precisely right check the [Mercurial Revsets Help](http://selenic.com/hg/help/revsets) -- they can do damn near anything and usually with clear syntax.